# Grouping and subsetting with multiple conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, group-by, summarize

I want to subset all this long-format dataset df for "Ca" and sum the percentages of the others elements into a new variable "other_elem" within the same column "Elements".

```
 tibble [225 × 8] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ site         : chr [1:225] "Nahal_Rahaf_2" "Nahal_Rahaf_2" "Nahal_Rahaf_2" "Nahal_Rahaf_2" ...
 $ site_type    : chr [1:225] "Rockshelter" "Rockshelter" "Rockshelter" "Rockshelter" ...
 $ aDNA_presence: chr [1:225] "No" "No" "No" "No" ...
 $ aDNA_quantity: chr [1:225] "No" "No" "No" "No" ...
 $ sample       : chr [1:225] "s1" "s1" "s1" "s1" ...
 $ Input_mg     : num [1:225] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Elements     : chr [1:225] "Mg" "Al" "Si" "P" ...
 $ Percentages  : num [1:225] 4.61 4.205 26.095 0.735 1.795 ...


head(df)

site          site_type   aDNA_presence aDNA_quantity sample Input_mg Elements Percentages
  <chr>         <chr>       <chr>         <chr>         <chr>     <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>
1 Nahal_Rahaf_2 Rockshelter No            No            s1            0 Mg             4.61 
2 Nahal_Rahaf_2 Rockshelter No            No            s1            0 Al             4.20 
3 Nahal_Rahaf_2 Rockshelter No            No            s1            0 Si            26.1  
4 Nahal_Rahaf_2 Rockshelter No            No            s1            0 P              0.735
5 Nahal_Rahaf_2 Rockshelter No            No            s1            0 K              1.80 
6 Nahal_Rahaf_2 Rockshelter No            No            s1            0 Ca            52.1
```

I have started writing the code but I get stuck to here:

```
group_by(Elements) %>% 
  summarise(Percentages = sum(Percentages))
```

Comment: `df %>% group_by(Elements = replace(Elements, Elements != "Ca", "other")) %>% summarise(Percentages = sum(Percentages))`

Comment: Thanks Darren, but I would also need to maintain the other columns though.. and not just "Elements" and "Percentages" columns.

Comment: It's probably a bit easier to help if we'd know the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group the data by all the columns except `Percentages`, overwrite `Elements` column by collapsing factors other than `"Ca"` into `"Others"`, and then summarize each group with `sum()`.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(pick(-Percentages),
           Elements = replace(Elements, Elements != "Ca", "Others")) %>%
  summarise(Percentages = sum(Percentages), .groups = 'drop')

# # A tibble: 2 × 8
#   site          site_type   aDNA_presence aDNA_quantity sample Input_mg Elements  Percentages
#   <chr>         <chr>       <chr>         <chr>         <chr>     <int> <chr>           <dbl>
# 1 Nahal_Rahaf_2 Rockshelter No            No            s1            0 Ca               52.1
# 2 Nahal_Rahaf_2 Rockshelter No            No            s1            0 Others           37.4
```

***Note:** If your `dplyr` version is older than `1.1.0`, replace `pick(-Percentages)` with `across(-Percentages)`.*

---

###### Data

```r
df <- read.table(text = "
  site          site_type   aDNA_presence aDNA_quantity sample Input_mg Elements Percentages
1 Nahal_Rahaf_2 Rockshelter No            No            s1            0 Mg             4.61 
2 Nahal_Rahaf_2 Rockshelter No            No            s1            0 Al             4.20 
3 Nahal_Rahaf_2 Rockshelter No            No            s1            0 Si            26.1  
4 Nahal_Rahaf_2 Rockshelter No            No            s1            0 P              0.735
5 Nahal_Rahaf_2 Rockshelter No            No            s1            0 K              1.80 
6 Nahal_Rahaf_2 Rockshelter No            No            s1            0 Ca            52.1")
```

Comment: Thats exactly what i wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To subset the data for "Ca" and sum the percentages of other elements into a new variable "other_elem", you can use the following code:

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  site = c("Nahal_Rahaf_2", "Nahal_Rahaf_2", "Nahal_Rahaf_2", "Nahal_Rahaf_2", "Nahal_Rahaf_2", "Nahal_Rahaf_2"),
  site_type = c("Rockshelter", "Rockshelter", "Rockshelter", "Rockshelter", "Rockshelter", "Rockshelter"),
  aDNA_presence = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"),
  aDNA_quantity = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No"),
  sample = c("s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1"),
  Input_mg = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  Elements = c("Mg", "Al", "Si", "P", "K", "Ca"),
  Percentages = c(4.61, 4.205, 26.095, 0.735, 1.795, 52.1)
)
```

Code:

```
df %>% 
  filter(Elements != "Ca") %>% 
  group_by(site, sample) %>% 
  summarize(other_elem = sum(Percentages)) %>% 
  full_join(df %>% filter(Elements == "Ca"), by = c("site", "sample")) %>% 
  arrange(site, sample)
```

Output:

```
# Groups:   site [1]
  site          sample other_elem site_type   aDNA_presence aDNA_quantity Input_mg Elements Percentages
  <chr>         <chr>       <dbl> <chr>       <chr>         <chr>            <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>
1 Nahal_Rahaf_2 s1           37.4 Rockshelter No            No                   0 Ca              52.1
```